# Avro optional json

Tags: json, avro

I have this json having field that optional only for a rare case. I always validated my json using Avro schema, and because I put it as required, it was failed.

Sample json normal case :

```
{"records" :[ {
        "unit": "< 50'000",
        "val1": "0.1000",
        "val2": "0.0000"
},{
        "unit": "< 150'000",
        "val1": "0.2000",
        "val2": "0.1000"
}]}
```

Sample json rare case ( val2 is optional)

```
{"records" :[ {
        "unit": "< 50'000",
        "val1": "0.1000"
},{
        "unit": "< 150'000",
        "val1": "0.2000"
}]
}
```

I was trying to change my schema to this :

```
{
  "name": "KafkaFCFD",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.myCompany.test",
  "fields": [
  {
   "name": "records",
   "type": {
   "type": "array",
   "items": {
      "name": "records_record",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "unit",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "val1",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "val2",
          "type": ["string","null"],
          "default": "0.0"
        }
       ]
      }
   }
 }
]
}
```

But this only gives me this exception :

```
Expected start-union. Got END_OBJECT
```

Any idea on how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run into this specifically myself yet (just starting working with avro), but in my readings I have seen people mention to invert the null declaration for union issues with null.

"type": ["null", "string"],